# Should we do something with [wlln] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that there is [wlln](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlln). Could you guess what does it stand for..? It has only 11 questions while the topic is pretty broad -- so I guess it is probably used less often than needed. Its name is hard to search if you do not know that it exists, so it is probably useless. Maybe it should be renamed or merged with other tag that has more informative name?

Comment: Weak law of large numbers

Comment: @Scortchi yes, I know, I read the tag wiki... My point is that the acronym is not the best choice for tags' name.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was on a quiz show for some reason, & just hit the buzzer; I didn't realize there was a wiki already. I think the acronym's fairly common but a synonym would certainly be a good idea.

Comment: @Scortchi Please join any quiz team I am in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 3:** Re-tagging finished.

**Update 2:** I wrote a wiki excerpt for [law-of-large-numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-large-numbers), put it on several most prominent old questions, and have now started retagging [wlln](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlln) into it.

**Update:** While this remains not implemented since December (!), [law-of-large-numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-large-numbers) has been created by somebody in June [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220775) and was by now used 4 times. The answer below is updated accordingly.

---

There is no tag on CV for the strong law of large numbers. Moreover, it seems that there is not enough questions about various laws of large numbers to warrant two different tags for the strong and the weak laws:

- [is:question "law of large numbers"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22law+of+large+numbers%22) -- 62 results
- [is:question "law of large numbers" score:5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22law+of+large+numbers%22+score%3A5) -- only 14 results
- [is:question "strong law of large numbers"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22strong+law+of+large+numbers%22) -- 12 results
- [is:question "weak law of large numbers"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22weak+law+of+large+numbers%22) -- 19 results

The total number of threads that could possibly be tagged with any of the related tags is probably well below 50 (with probably only 10-20 "notable" questions). That's not that many. And currently these questions are not united by any tag at all, which is a pity.

**I would therefore suggest to use the generic tag [law-of-large-numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-large-numbers) as the only tag for all these questions.**

Comment: There is no consensus in this case. Maybe let's discuss @amoeba's (and mine) proposal? What are the cons of this idea?

Answer (score 3):

"Could you guess what does it stand for..?" -- yes, easily, since it's a common abbreviation for a standard term.

But the fact that many of us here would know shouldn't be the test.

There's a technical issue:

While `weak-law-of-large-numbers` *just* fits in the character limit for tags, `strong-law-of-large-numbers` would not. As such, Scortchi's suggestion of a synonym makes sense - since we can cut off the longer tag at 25 characters and then when someone starts typing it - it would bring up the shorter one which would remap to `slln`.

That is, I think the long terms need to be synonyms of the short ones.

Comment: So maybe we don't need to be so precise and `[law-of-large-numbers]` is enough..?

Comment: The distinction can be be pretty central to some questions. Possibly we could have `law-of-large-numbers` along with `weak-law` and `strong-law` when needed, which can have synonyms that point to them.

Comment: Ah ... I didn't know about the character limit. I've swapped them, at least for now.

Comment: @Glen_b central -- yes -- but for taxonomic reasons maybe it is enough? I doubt that there is/will be that much questions on WLLN and SLLN combined that it would be hard to search through them.

Comment: @Scortchi at least, as far as I know it's still 25 characters -- I may have missed something though

Comment: It is; I've just checked.

Comment: The names could be [weak-law-of-large-n] and [strong-law-of-large-n]. However, I notice that there is no tag for the strong law at all! From this I conclude that there is not enough questions on CV to warrant this difference and would perhaps go with @Tim's suggestion of making all these tags synonyms of [law-of-large-numbers].

Comment: @Glen_b what do you think about amoebas proposal? This thread seems to be slowly dying while IMHO amoebas proposal is simple and reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I've made [wlln](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlln) a synonym of [weak-law-of-large-numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-law-of-large-numbers).

Comment: I think it needs to be the other way around. see my answer.

Comment: Maybe you could comment on amoebas proposal? This thread seems to be slowly dying while IMHO amoebas proposal is simple and reasonable.

Comment: I retagged all wlln into law-of-large-numbers (see updates to my answer above); consequently, wlln has been deleted. However, your synonym still exists; I guess synonyms do not  get automatically removed in such situations. Should we delete it (now both tags still appear as pop-ups when looking for tags)?

Comment: @amoeba: Thanks, I've deleted the existing synonym. Do we now want to make  [law-of-large-numbers] a master & [weak-law-of-large-numbers] a synonym?

Comment: @Scortchi I'd say there is no need for that; whoever starts typing "law" of "large" will get [law-of-large-numbers] as suggestion, so I don't see how the presence of [weak/strong-law-of-law-numbers] would help.

Comment: @amoeba: I was thinking of someone who started typing "weak-law[...]"

Comment: Hmm, yes, good point. I guess we could make [weak-law-of-large-n] and [strong-law-of-large-n] pointing at the [law-of-large-numbers].